# is this proof correct - If K is algebraic over F, L is algebraic over K then L is algebraic over F

Tags: ring-theory

I solved this theorem using following. pls correct if my approach is correct or not
theorem - given field extensions K,L, F, If K is algebraic over F, L is algebraic over K then L is algebraic over F

Let $a \in L$ be algebraic over K, then $ \exists f(x) \in K[x]  :f(a) = 0 $.

let 
$f(x)=a_0 +a_1x+a_2x^2+....+a_nx^n : a_i \forall i \in K$

As $a_i \in K $ and K is algebraic over F  $\implies \exists $ another  $g_i(x) : g_i(a_i)=0$;
Let $g_i(x)=b_{i0} +b_{i1}x+b_{i2}x^2+....+b_{in}x^n : b_{ij}  \in F \forall i,j$

then $f(a) = g_{0}(a_0)+g_1(a_1)a+g_2(a_2)a^2+...+g_n(a_n)a^n = 0$ where $g_i(a_i) \in F$
this means f(a) = Span[$1,a,a^2...a^n$] with coordinates from field F.

$\implies$ $f(x) = g_{0}(x)+g_1(x)x+g_2(x)x^2+...+g_n(x)x^n = 0$ where $g_i(x) =  b_{i0} +b_{i1}x+b_{i2}x^2+....+b_{in}x^n : b_{ij}  \in F \forall i,j$

Now f(x) has coefficients from F

This means $a \in L$ is algebraic over F. So L is algebraic over F

Pls correct me is i am wrong.

Comment: The proof does not work as written. You already know that $f(a)=0$, hence $f(a)$ is element of any span of whatever elements.

Comment: Here my constructed f(x) has cooeffients from F(initiallly from K, as K is algebraic over F, i each cooefficient in K is algebraic over F)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen pls verify my constructed f(x) [i have edited now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I did not understand what $f(a) = g_0(a_0)+...+g_n(a_n)a^n$ is supposed to mean. To me it reads as $0 = 0$.

I would argue with dimensionality. Any finite field extension $L/K$ (i.e. $dim_K L \leq \infty$) is algebraic.

You have stated that $a\in F[a_0,...a_n]$, which is a finite field extension of $F$ proving the claim.

Edit: Writing down the minimal polynomial for $a$ with coefficients in $F$ is not so easy, I think.